# Panel that will display pictures when jlable is moused over

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I would like to have jpanel1 invisible until one of the jlabels is moused over. JPanel1 must then become visible and a JLable(called jLabel1) must set it's image to the one of the JLabel that is being moused over.

```
public GUI() 
{

    initComponents();
    jPanel1.setVisible(false);



    for(int i =4; i<12;i++)
    {
        JLabel l = new JLabel();
        l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i+".jpg"));
        p1.add(l);
    }
    for(int i =12; i<20;i++)
    {
        JLabel l = new JLabel();
        l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i+".jpg"));
        p2.add(l);
    }
}
```

below are links to 2 pictures of my program, one in the design view showing the side panel and the other of the actual program when it is running. I would like for the JPanel on the left to become visible when the user mouses over one of the jlabels in the picture grid(see screenshot of running program). The jLabel at the top of the panel on the left must set its image to the image which the user mousing over in the image grid.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also consider posting images (or links to images that we can insert for you) that show what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would like to add photo's but my account reputation does not allow me to in the post. Is there any other way of adding images?

Comment: Someone is working on editing your question so that the images will show. 1+ for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that you've got a grid of **thumbnail** ImageIcons held in a grid of JLabel, and that you want to display a larger image of the thumbnail to the left of the grid. If so:

- I wouldn't make a JPanel appear and disappear.
- Instead have a JPanel that holds a JLabel sit on the left.
- Give your JLabels MouseMotionListeners.
- When the mouse enters a label, then have the listener get the appropriate large ImageIcon, the one that corresponds to the thumbnail, and have the large JLabel on the left display it via `setIcon(...)`.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> I see how this would work, although I do not know how to get the appropriate image icon because all of the JLabels on the right that currently have the pictures are named the same name(from my for loop). How would I get the individual JLabel information(in this case the ImageIcon of that JLabel.

Please understand that variable names aren't all that important, and instead what matters are object **references**. One possible solution, create a Map, such as a `HashMap<Icon, Icon>`. If you do this, you could associate each small thumbnail ImageIcon with its larger ImageIcon. Then in your MouseMotionListener, get the label that the mouse enters via `(JLabel) getSource()`, get its thumbnail icon via `getIcon()`, and if not null (check!), use your map to get the larger Icon that is associated with the thumbnail.

Comment: I see how this would work, although I do not know how to get the appropriate image icon because all of the JLabels on the right that currently have the pictures are named the same name(from my for loop). How would I get the individual JLabel information(in this case the ImageIcon of that JLabel.

Comment: @d00by: please see edit to answer.

Comment: I am not familiar with maps or hashmaps, could you maybe give me an example of how it would look in my code? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: @d00by: Lots of HashMap tutorials to be found easily with Google, and I recommend that you give one or two a look.